# in my C# code i am getting this type of Error

Tags: c#

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'
Inner Exception
Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You're giving us *no* details about your code, just presenting the text of an error message. How do you expect us to help you?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solutions :**

1- Check your connection string name and syntax.

2- Restart your SQL server.

3- Open services from your windows and restart the process of SQL because sometimes it stopes suddenly.

4- Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections:

Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
Enable local and remote connections
Restart instance